# My textures are stretched when attempting to apply a texture to a certain part of the model

Tags: texturing, uv

[image: As you can see here, the texture is only correctly applied to the flat surface. The texture is otherwise stretched and distorted throughout the whole model.]

[image: In this you can see that the model is stretched oddly in the UV editor. What am I doing wrong? Do I make my 3d models wrong? Because it looks very messed up.]

Please help me, I am simple trying to texture this model. The textures are all stretched out and look awfully glitchy. I am wondering if I am modelling incorrectly as I have seen other people not run into this problem.

Comment: Have you unwrapped the UVs with any edges marked as seams? Have you tried _Smart UV Project_?

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to blender stack !
the **problem is with your uv** . its not unwrapped in a correct way [image]
did you use seams in the correct location ?? maybe you left out some plcaes if you haven't used any seam then this tutorial will help you for sure >>>>

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=scPSP_U858k&list=PLjEaoINr3zgHJVJF3T3CFUAZ6z11jKg6a&index=6

or just **select the area where the texture isn't correct in edit mode and press u and click on unwrap**,it may help . Or send me the blend files i could surely help you out .